# Pandas: import multiple dataframes, change headers and append them in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I was analysing crypto data using a library called [ccxt](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt).
With ccxt, I can easily get candlestick for crypto datafeed into dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import config
import ccxt
import json
import csv

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'enableRateLimit': True, 
    'options': {'defaultType': 'future'}
})

 
name = exchange.fetch_ohlcv('BTC/USDT', limit=5, timeframe='1m')
btc = pd.DataFrame(name, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
 
print(btc)
```

single crypto Output:

```
       timestamp      open      high       low     close   volume
0  1620202740000  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  118.239
1  1620202800000  54978.49  55054.00  54972.04  55027.12  337.619
2  1620202860000  55027.12  55041.05  54950.05  54951.96  131.414
3  1620202920000  54951.96  55067.36  54951.95  55063.78  176.529
4  1620202980000  55063.79  55064.00  55000.00  55014.39  107.082
```

I wanted to import multiple cryptos into one dataframe with two-level headers, something like the following.

```
                      btc       btc        btc     btc     btc      eth        eth       eth      eth     eth                      
       timestamp     open      high       low     close   volume    open      high       low     close    volume  
0  1620202740000  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  118.239  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  4345
1  1620202800000  54978.49  55054.00  54972.04  55027.12  337.619  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  134.239   
2  1620202860000  55027.12  55041.05  54950.05  54951.96  131.414  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  14358.239
3  1620202920000  54951.96  55067.36  54951.95  55063.78  176.529  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  1148.239
4  1620202980000  55063.79  55064.00  55000.00  55014.39  107.082  54945.31  54987.01  54945.30  54978.49  18.239
```

In that way I can create columns for multiple crypto at the same time, such as

```
for x in ['btc', 'eth']:
    df.loc[:, (x, 'fast_ema_1min')] = df[x]['close'].rolling(window=1).mean()
    df.loc[:, (x, 'slow_ema_20min')] = df[x]['close'].rolling(window=20).mean()
```

I have tried

```
basket = [['BTC', 'BTC/USDT'], ['ETH', 'ETH/USDT'], ['ADA', 'ADA/USDT']]
appended_data = []
for i, name in basket:
    i = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(name, limit=5, timeframe='1m')
    i = pd.DataFrame(i, columns=[['_', name, name, name, name,name], ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']])
    appended_data.append(i)
    print(appended_data)
print(appended_data.head(5))
```

However, I got error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Can someone advise? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try retaining your code of aggregating a list of dataframes and then concat them after the loop, like below:

```
pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks  @seabean

I followed your method, and I got this error



```
UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left,2 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Comment: @FlyUFalcon  Normally we will start with an empty dataframe outside the loop and then append to the dataframe.  In your case where you want to concat the columns, you might need to use a list to hold multiple dataframes and then concat the list outside the loop.

Comment: @FlyUFalcon  See my edit above.  concat the list of dataframes after the loop.

Comment: @FlyUFalcon  Anyway, as the timestamps for each section may be different from those of other sections, it would be more complicated to join / concat them.  You may need to merge them with the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SeaBean

I managed to solve the problem.

```
appended_data = []
 
basket = [['BTC', 'BTC/USDT'], ['ETH', 'ETH/USDT'], ['ADA', 'ADA/USDT']]
for i, name in basket:
    i = exchange.fetch_ohlcv(name, limit=5, timeframe='1m')
    i = pd.DataFrame(i, columns=[['_', name, name, name, name,name], ['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']])
    appended_data.append(i)
    df = pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: You can put the last line `df = pd.concat(...)` outside of the loop since you only need to concat the aggregated list of dataframes once only which can be done after the loop.